# Add Custom Labels to gutenberg latest posts block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, wordpress-hook

I have a page that displays latest posts from specific category via gutenberg's block. Now I would like to add "New" label at the top left corner on the posts' images. I found inside

```
wp-includes/blocks/latest-posts.php
```

the code for this block and add a custom hook inside of it

```
add_action( 'da_custom_labels', 'render_block_core_latest_posts' );
```

After that, I wrote inside my `functions.php` the function for the hook:

```
add_filter('da_custom_labels','da_custom_labels_sales_posts');
function da_custom_labels_sales_posts() {
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'new_real_estate', true ); //custom field
}
```

I tried many different things, but all the labels appear at one row.. Sothing like this:

```
NewNewNewNewNewNew
<ul>
  <li> ... </li>
  <li> ... </li>
  <li> ... </li>
  <li> ... </li>
</ul>
```

Thus, I would like to have the "New" label inside every `li` and not like that, so I could apply CSS and anything else necessary.

Any ideas how I could accomplise that? Or any other work arround - solution?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I could not find any proper hook or filter in order to add my own custom functions. Thus, best way to do this is by overwritting the block itself. Inside `functions.php` of `child theme` I have add the below code:

```
add_filter( 'register_block_type_args', 'core_latest_posts_block_type_args', 10, 3 );
function core_latest_posts_block_type_args( $args, $name ) {
    if ( $name == 'core/latest-posts' ) {
        $args['render_callback'] = 'modify_core_latest_posts'; //call custom gutenberg block
    }
    return $args;
}

function modify_core_latest_posts($attributes) { //copy and paste the block as is, but adding custom code too
    global $post, $block_core_latest_posts_excerpt_length;

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'      => $attributes['postsToShow'],
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'order'               => $attributes['order'],
        'orderby'             => $attributes['orderBy'],
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
        'no_found_rows'       => true,
    );

    $block_core_latest_posts_excerpt_length = $attributes['excerptLength'];

    if ( isset( $attributes['categories'] ) ) {
        $args['category__in'] = array_column( $attributes['categories'], 'id' );
    }
    if ( isset( $attributes['selectedAuthor'] ) ) {
        $args['author'] = $attributes['selectedAuthor'];
    }

    $query        = new WP_Query;
    $recent_posts = $query->query( $args );

    if ( isset( $attributes['displayFeaturedImage'] ) && $attributes['displayFeaturedImage'] ) {
        update_post_thumbnail_cache( $query );
    }

    $list_items_markup = '';

    foreach ( $recent_posts as $post ) {
        $post_link = esc_url( get_permalink( $post ) );
        $title     = get_the_title( $post );

        if ( ! $title ) {
            $title = __( '(no title)' );
        }

        $list_items_markup .= '<li>';

        $real_new = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'real_new'); //get custom field - custom code adding label on images
        if($real_new) {
            if ($real_new[0]) {
                $list_items_markup .= "<span style='position:relative;top:0;left:0;z-index:99;'>" . $real_new[0] . "</span>";
            }
        }

        if ( $attributes['displayFeaturedImage'] && has_post_thumbnail( $post ) ) {
            $image_style = '';
            if ( isset( $attributes['featuredImageSizeWidth'] ) ) {
                $image_style .= sprintf( 'max-width:%spx;', $attributes['featuredImageSizeWidth'] );
            }
            if ( isset( $attributes['featuredImageSizeHeight'] ) ) {
                $image_style .= sprintf( 'max-height:%spx;', $attributes['featuredImageSizeHeight'] );
            }

            $image_classes = 'wp-block-latest-posts__featured-image';
            if ( isset( $attributes['featuredImageAlign'] ) ) {
                $image_classes .= ' align' . $attributes['featuredImageAlign'];
            }

            $featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail(
                $post,
                $attributes['featuredImageSizeSlug'],
                array(
                    'style' => esc_attr( $image_style ),
                )
            );
            if ( $attributes['addLinkToFeaturedImage'] ) {
                $featured_image = sprintf(
                    '<a href="%1$s" aria-label="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
                    esc_url( $post_link ),
                    esc_attr( $title ),
                    $featured_image
                );
            }
            $list_items_markup .= sprintf(
                '<div class="%1$s">%2$s</div>',
                esc_attr( $image_classes ),
                $featured_image
            );
        }

        $list_items_markup .= sprintf(
            '<a class="wp-block-latest-posts__post-title" href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
            esc_url( $post_link ),
            $title
        );

        if ( isset( $attributes['displayAuthor'] ) && $attributes['displayAuthor'] ) {
            $author_display_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );

            /* translators: byline. %s: current author. */
            $byline = sprintf( __( 'by %s' ), $author_display_name );

            if ( ! empty( $author_display_name ) ) {
                $list_items_markup .= sprintf(
                    '<div class="wp-block-latest-posts__post-author">%1$s</div>',
                    $byline
                );
            }
        }

        if ( isset( $attributes['displayPostDate'] ) && $attributes['displayPostDate'] ) {
            $list_items_markup .= sprintf(
                '<time datetime="%1$s" class="wp-block-latest-posts__post-date">%2$s</time>',
                esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c', $post ) ),
                get_the_date( '', $post )
            );
        }

        if ( isset( $attributes['displayPostContent'] ) && $attributes['displayPostContent']
            && isset( $attributes['displayPostContentRadio'] ) && 'excerpt' === $attributes['displayPostContentRadio'] ) {

            $trimmed_excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $post );

            if ( post_password_required( $post ) ) {
                $trimmed_excerpt = __( 'This content is password protected.' );
            }

            $list_items_markup .= sprintf(
                '<div class="wp-block-latest-posts__post-excerpt">%1$s</div>',
                $trimmed_excerpt
            );
        }

        if ( isset( $attributes['displayPostContent'] ) && $attributes['displayPostContent']
            && isset( $attributes['displayPostContentRadio'] ) && 'full_post' === $attributes['displayPostContentRadio'] ) {

            $post_content = html_entity_decode( $post->post_content, ENT_QUOTES, get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );

            if ( post_password_required( $post ) ) {
                $post_content = __( 'This content is password protected.' );
            }

            $list_items_markup .= sprintf(
                '<div class="wp-block-latest-posts__post-full-content">%1$s</div>',
                wp_kses_post( $post_content )
            );
        }

        $list_items_markup .= "</li>\n";
    }

    remove_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'block_core_latest_posts_get_excerpt_length', 20 );

    $class = 'wp-block-latest-posts__list';

    if ( isset( $attributes['postLayout'] ) && 'grid' === $attributes['postLayout'] ) {
        $class .= ' is-grid';
    }

    if ( isset( $attributes['columns'] ) && 'grid' === $attributes['postLayout'] ) {
        $class .= ' columns-' . $attributes['columns'];
    }

    if ( isset( $attributes['displayPostDate'] ) && $attributes['displayPostDate'] ) {
        $class .= ' has-dates';
    }

    if ( isset( $attributes['displayAuthor'] ) && $attributes['displayAuthor'] ) {
        $class .= ' has-author';
    }

    $wrapper_attributes = get_block_wrapper_attributes( array( 'class' => $class ) );

    return sprintf(
        '<ul %1$s>%2$s</ul>',
        $wrapper_attributes,
        $list_items_markup
    );
}
```

of course, it could be done via a custom plugin for better managing and organizing your files. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

a good Alternative is the Query Loop Block (see https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/query-loop-block/). It is called a "a more complex and powerful Latest Posts Block".

With the Query Loop Block you can customize the post template which is used within the query block.

I think in this way you can add code to your latest posts at least with shortcodes.

Good look :)